# Compilado .pyw a .exe pero no añadio las librerias

Tags: python

Compile mi archivo .pyw a .exe pero no sé porque las dependencias no fueron agregadas. Digamos que mi programa requiere de unas cuantas dependencias que instale en mi ordenador. Pero por algun motivo no fueron agregados. A continuación, muestro el error obtenido:

> ```
> historial.exe -h
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "historial.pyw", line 21, in <module>
>   File "historial\softwares\browsers\mozilla.pyc", line 15, in <module>
> ImportError: No module named pyasn1.codec.der
> ```

La cuestión es que estas librerías externas como las agrego a mi .exe. El comando que use fue:

```
python setup.pyw py2exe
```

Instale sigue mostrando:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "laZagne.pyw", line 21, in
>      File "lazagne\softwares\browsers\mozilla.pyc", line 15, in
>    ImportError: No module named pyasn1.codec.der

setup.pyw con las dll que exclui tal vez eso?:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['laZagne.pyw'],options={'py2exe': { 
"dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll","libzmq.pyd","geos_c.dll","api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll","api-ms-win-core-registry-l1-1-0.dll","api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-1.dll","api-ms-win-core-string-l2-1-0.dll","api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll","api-ms-win*.dll","api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-2.dll","api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-1.dll","api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-1.dll","api-ms-win-security-base-l1-2-0.dll","api-ms-win-eventing-provider-l1-1-0.dll","api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0.dll","api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll","api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1.dll","api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1.dll","api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll","api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-2-0.dll","api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll","api-ms-win-core-io-l1-1-1.dll","api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-1.dll","api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-2.dll","api-ms-win-core-version-l1-1-1.dll","api-ms-win-core-version-l1-1-0.dll","api-ms-win-core-delayload-l1-1-1.dll","api-ms-win-core-apiquery-l1-1-0.dll"]
}})
```

El motivo me esta alertando que han sido perdidos!:
The following modules appear to be missing

> ['Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', 'Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath',
>   'ElementC14N', 'POW', '_psutil_linux', '_sysconfigdata', 'colorama',
>   'enum', 'ordereddict', 'ordereddict.ordereddict',
>   'psutil._psutil_bsd', 'psutil._psutil_osx', 'psutil._psutil_posix',
>   'psutil._psutil_sunos', 'pyasn1.codec.der', 'pyasn1.type', 'winreg']

Que tengo que hacer para agregarlas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues hace falta instalar dicho módulo , descargar desde aquí https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyasn1#downloads , Instalar mediante los pasos que ahí le indican. y luego volver a intentar.

Comment: lo que no entiendo es porque se me pierden si los tengo instalados!

Comment: puede que sea porque excluyo estas librerias probare en windows 7 Lol pero no creo que se solucione

Comment: this issue is solved i have other now